# Italian cantillation

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-reading, trop-cantillation, italy

I'm interested in learning the Italian system for the ta'amei hamikra, either for Torah and/or Haftarah (preference to Haftarah as the Italian melodies are very beautiful). [This website](http://www.archivio-torah.it/HTM/indiceaudio.htm) has tons of recordings, with davening as well. But does anyone know of a resource where the trope themselves are demonstrated? I'm especially concerned because in the recordings, there often seems to be little differentiation between the various trope.

Comment: It's not just Italians that do it slightly different from each other -- everyone does, no matter what system they use. Each leiner has their own touches.

Comment: I think you mistook me. I didn't mean that a particular trope is preformed differently here and there, but rather that *different* trope seem to be done in more or less the same way. From the Haftarah recordings that I've listened to, it almost seems like the reader is mostly singing a free tune, with the etnachtas and siluks being the only readily distinguishable teamim.

Comment: I am Italian and know the Italian torah trops. Just to point out though, that there are different trops within the various communities in Italy and you need to be careful when it comes to Italy as there are 2 main established minhaghim: Bene' romi - which is the main one encompassing 70% of the Italian Jews - is older than 2,000 years, since the second galut (some say even before); Spanish/Portuguese - this is Sephardic and its trops (in terms of sung teamim) are exactly the same as any other Sephardic minhag. Let me know if you need more and I will be happy to assist you more.

Answer (score 5):

[This website](http://learntoleyn.weebly.com/italian-torah.html) demonstrates the Italian Torah trope.

Comment: T.W., [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for sharing this source! You could make this answer even more valuable by [edit]ing in some more information (as much as you can) about what website you're citing, who made it, etc. Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: One problem I see is that the recordings linked seem to be a woman singing.

Comment: "The" Italian tradition. As mentioned in other comments, there are/were at least 10-20 different of them...

Comment: There are not 10-20 different traditions in Italy. There are slight variations between the local communities but the siddur is the same for this nusach.

Comment: I'm not sure whether a woman or a child sings on the samples. In any case the singer has an audible English accent. Are there any active Italkì communities in the Anglo world? If not, I wonder how come the samples aren't recorded by someone who really prays with this nusach...

Comment: @Aviel Shall I start to list? Rome, Ancona, Milan-Turin, Venice Sefardi, Venice Ashkenazi, Venice Italian, Livorno, Gorizia, Trieste Sefardi, Trieste Ashkenazi, Verona. And add old the Middle Easterns that came later. [Next time if you want me too see your answer, please use @]